# Symbol preventing Import from web in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA and trying to record a macro that imports the table from this website:

https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=CAD&amount=1

I can import it manually just fine, but when recoding the macro, VBA does not understand the triangle symbol used in the heading and replaces it with a question mark in the VBA code.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried removing/replacing the question mark in the VBA code, but then it does not match the table and I get an error because the heading couldn't be found. I've also tried transforming the data when recording the macro and removing the triangles from the headings, but no luck.

Does anybody have a way to work around this? Below is the code from the recorded macro if it helps. Thanks!

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=CAD&amount=1""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data1 = Source{1}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{""Canadian Dollar?"", type text}, {""1.00 CAD??"", type number}, {""inv. 1.00 CAD??"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 1"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Comment: You need the macro to import this table or refresh it once imported?

Comment: Also, it appears a line has been removed from your code: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add` This was above the `With` statement. When the code adds that page, that page becomes the `activesheet`. I don't know if this is the issue, but it seems worth investigating

Comment: Both. The goal is a userform that will allow the user to import the data, refresh it, and display a few other metrics. During the macro I loaded the table into an existing sheet, perhaps that's why the line to add a new work sheet was removed.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the error.  The error I had was due to my running the macro from VBA where I had changed the sheet name to sheets(2). It wouldn't run unless I made sheet 2 active in the application window (meaning I clicked on the tab for sheet two then ran the macro)